# How to get module/controller/action by route?

Tags: php, yii

Route:

```
"login" => "module/users/login",
```

How to get module/controller/action by route (`login`) ?

Comment: what you exactly want to do? login to mudule only or both login to site and module?

Answer (score 0):

can route login module as
 in config/main.php

```
...
'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
   'rules'=>array(
        '<action>/*'=>'modules/user/<action>',
   ),
)
...
```

it converts the url from

```
$url = Yii::app()->createUrl('modules/user/login');
```

to

```
/login
```

Comment: i need in reverse order: `someMethod('login') -> 'module/users/login'`

Comment: rewrite url in .htaccess file and do as above.